# R: compare two sets of lubridates dates

Tags: r, lubridate

I try to find the intersection of two vectors of lubridate dates. However, after, applying the `lubridate::intersect` function, the dates are converted to double.

```
library(lubridate)
> a <- c(ymd("2017-01-01"), ymd("2017-01-02"), ymd("2017-01-03"), ymd("2017-01-04"))
> b <- c(ymd("2017-01-02"), ymd("2017-01-03"), ymd("2017-01-04"), ymd("2017-01-05"))
> lubridate::intersect(a, b)
[1] 17168 17169 17170
```

How can the original date type be preserved?

Comment: There is no such thing as "lubridate dates".

Comment: its just to say "dates created with the libridate::ymd function"

Comment: Those are just objects of class `Date`. It doesn't matter how you create them.

Comment: Note that lubridate doesn't define an `intersect` method for dates. There is only an S4 method for intervals. You are actually using `base::intersect` there and that doesn't preserve the class (only the mode).

Comment: See here? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html

Comment: Must have misunderstood the vignette then..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can convert it back to `Date` with `as.Date` by specifying the `origin`

```
as.Date(lubridate::intersect(a, b), origin = '1970-01-01')
#[1] "2017-01-02" "2017-01-03" "2017-01-04"
```